# Uniform convergence doesn't imply convergence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We have a theorem in our course that;

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^p, 1 ≤ p < ∞$, which converges μ-a.e. to a measurable function $f$. Suppose there exists $g ∈ L^p$ such that $|f_n| ≤ g$ for all $n∈\mathbb{N}$. Then $f ∈L^p$, and $f_n →f$ in $L^p$.

To show that uniform convergence doesn't imply $L^p$ convergence we are given the example of $f_n := 1/n\chi_{[0,n]}$. This uniformly converges to the zero function but the $L^p$ norm for each $f_n$ is equal to $1$. This doesn't contradict the above theorem because it "cannot be dominated".

I am struggling to see how this sequence can't be dominated so any hints would be helpful. For example any constant function > 1?

Comment: If it could be "dominated" you could apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I understand that but surely take any constant function > 1. Then this would dominate every $f_n$?

Comment: In the DCT you need the dominating function to have a finite integral.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a dominating function has to dominate all or at least all but finitely many of the functions in the sequence, so the obvious way to define a dominating function in a "reasonably tight" manner would be to have $g(x)=1/\lceil x \rceil$ (which actually is tight as a dominating function, since it is exactly $\sup_n f_n(x)$). But this function is not integrable at infinity (by comparison with, say, $1/(x+1)$), so it cannot be a dominating function for DCT.